# Universal Tween Manger smooth screen transition on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-animation, tween

I am fairly new to tweening concept and libgdx library.

I am able to tween objects on screen.
How can i apply tweens like (fadeIn., etc) while transitioning to another screen?

I want to achieve something similar to **[Tween Engine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aurelienribon.tweenengine.demo&hl=en_IN)** app on google play

**Code snippet to go to next screen**

```
Tween.to(bgSprite,SpriteTween.OPACITY,3.0f).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, 2.0f).
                setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
                ((Game)(Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())).setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
            }
        }).start(MainMultiple.tweenManager);
```

Comment: Simplest way is to draw a screen-sized black texture region over the entire screen and use a tween for it's opacity. Fade to Black when leaving a screen and fade in from black on the other screen. Don't draw the region while it has zero opacity, because it is wasted drawn pixels.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am currently trying this idea.